# powershell send-mailmessage is sending duplicate emails when user is present in multiple DL

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am using the below powershell script to send the email to me and my team DL.

After running the below script only ONCE, i and manager are getting 2 Mails each which are same, Becuase i and he are in the DL_team@domain.com.
Why this is happing. Is it send-mailmessage issue or smtp or exchange.

How can i get one email though DL is in "TO:"

```
$smtpserver = "smtp@domain.com"
$To = @("me@domain.com","DL_team@domain.com")
$Cc = @("manger@domain.com")
$subject = "Alert when fail"
Send-MailMessage -from Alert@domain.com -To $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $subject -Body "Alert" -SmtpServer $smtpserver
```

Comment: Well, you (me@domain.com) are in the `$To`, aswell as the group DL_team@domain.com, so that is one mail via the group and one mail directly to you. Almost the same for the manager who gets the mail via the group, but also via the CC. Looks pretty obvious to me that both of you receive this email twice..

Comment: Is there any way, it should be recieved just once. My previous alert mail was in talend ETL which never sent duplicate mails. Even when i send thorough my outlook office 365. It is received only once.

Comment: Sure, just remove your email address from the `$To` and leave `$Cc` empty, OR remove yourself and the manager from the DL (but I don't think you want to do that)

Answer (score 0):

This is a mail server configuration problem, not a code one. We cannot help you here with the configuration of your mail server as it's off topic for StackOverflow ([ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) may be able to assist you here).

But you *can* workaround it in your code by removing any duplicate users present on a mailing list in the `To/CC/BCC` fields.